# How to pass parameter in select query(In with clause) and not in where condition in SQl Server SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, cte, parameter

I want to pass a parameter (`@date1`) in my SSIS OLE DB Source so I created a variable and I tried to pass the parameter using '`?`' but it's showing 'Syntax error, permission violation or other non-specific error'

I tried like this:

```
select dateAdd(second, 1, @date1=?) StartTime, --Selecting calls from the next second of last processed time. 
convert(datetime, convert(char(19), dateAdd(minute, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 120)) EndTime --TRIM to seconds.
```

But I know I can pass parameter in where condition but I want to Pass it in select.

*Exact With Query:*

```
select dateAdd(second, 1, @date1) StartTime, --Selecting calls from the next second of last processed time. 
convert(datetime, convert(char(19), dateAdd(minute, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 120)) EndTime --TRIM to seconds.
```

Full Query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_CAll_LEVEL_DETAILS] ( @date1 DateTime )
As
With BACK_LOG_PICK(StartTime, ENDTIME) as
(
select dateAdd(second, 1, @date1) StartTime, --Selecting calls from the next second of last processed time. 
convert(datetime, convert(char(19), dateAdd(minute, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 120)) EndTime --TRIM to seconds.
--15 mins is considered as max call time. So calls before 15 mins are backloged and selected.

--select '18-mar-2014 18:52:00' StartTime,
--'18-mar-2014 18:54:00' EndTime
),
TCD(RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,CallStartTime,CallEndTime)
As
(
select RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey
,Min(DateTime) as CallStartTime, Max(DateTime) as CallEndTime from Termination_Call_Detail
where DigitsDialed in('30013900', '30013901')
group by RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey
having Min(DateTime)>=(Select StartTime from BACK_LOG_PICK) 
and Min(DateTime) < (Select ENDTIME from BACK_LOG_PICK)
--Any Call started between our interested time is selected, even if the call is not ended in our time interval.
),
TCDRecords (AgentSkillTargetID,SkillGroupSkillTargetID,ServiceSkillTargetID,PeripheralID,RouteID,
  RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,DateTime,PeripheralCallType,DigitsDialed,PeripheralCallKey,
  CallDisposition,NetworkTime,Duration,RingTime,DelayTime,TimeToAband,HoldTime,TalkTime,
  WorkTime,LocalQTime,CallSegmentTime,ConferenceTime,NetworkTargetID,TrunkGroupID,DNIS,
  InstrumentPortNumber,AgentPeripheralNumber,ICRCallKey,ICRCallKeyParent,ICRCallKeyChild,
  ANI,AnsweredWithinServiceLevel,Priority,Trunk,CallDispositionFlag,RouterCallKeySequenceNumber,
  CED,CallTypeID,BadCallTag,ApplicationTaskDisposition,ApplicationData,NetQTime,CallTypeReportingDateTime,
       NetworkSkillGroupQTime,EnterpriseQueueTime) as
(
select AgentSkillTargetID,SkillGroupSkillTargetID,ServiceSkillTargetID,PeripheralID,RouteID,
  b.RouterCallKeyDay,b.RouterCallKey,DateTime,PeripheralCallType,DigitsDialed,PeripheralCallKey,
  CallDisposition,NetworkTime,Duration,RingTime,DelayTime,TimeToAband,HoldTime,TalkTime,
  WorkTime,LocalQTime,CallSegmentTime,ConferenceTime,NetworkTargetID,TrunkGroupID,DNIS,
  InstrumentPortNumber,AgentPeripheralNumber,ICRCallKey,ICRCallKeyParent,ICRCallKeyChild,
  ANI,AnsweredWithinServiceLevel,Priority,Trunk,CallDispositionFlag,RouterCallKeySequenceNumber,
  CED,CallTypeID,BadCallTag,ApplicationTaskDisposition,ApplicationData,NetQTime,CallTypeReportingDateTime,
  NetworkSkillGroupQTime,EnterpriseQueueTime from Termination_Call_Detail a , TCD b 
  where a.RouterCallKey = b.RouterCallKey  and a.RouterCallKeyDay = b.RouterCallKeyDay 
  --and Min(DateTime)>=(Select StartTime from BACK_LOG_PICK) 
--and Max(DateTime) < (Select ENDTIME from BACK_LOG_PICK) 
),
CallDisposition(RouterCallKey, RouterCallKeyDay, Hangup_Flag) as
(
select RouterCallKey, RouterCallKeyDay, 
(
case 
when max(CallDisposition) = 52 then 'AD' 
else 
    case 
    when max(CallDisposition) = 13 then 'CD' 
    else 'SD' 
    end 
end) as Hangup_Flag 
from TCDRecords group by RouterCallKey, RouterCallKeyDay
),
callType1prepare(RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,Duration, LocalQTime)
As
(
select distinct RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey, MAX(Duration), SUM(LocalQTime) from TCDRecords 
WHERE PeripheralCallType =1 
 group by RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey
),
CallType1PrepareDistinct(RowNumber,RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,DateTime, DigitsDialed, DNIS, 

ANI,CallDisposition,NetworkTime,Duration,RingTime,DelayTime,TimeToAband,HoldTime,
  WorkTime,LocalQTime,CallSegmentTime,ConferenceTime,NetworkSkillGroupQTime,EnterpriseQueueTime) as
(
select Row_Number() Over(Partition by b.RouterCallKeyDay,b.RouterCallKey Order By b.RouterCallKeyDay,b.RouterCallKey 

desc) As RowNumber,
        b.RouterCallKeyDay,b.RouterCallKey, DateTime, DigitsDialed, DNIS, ANI,CallDisposition,NetworkTime, 

b.Duration,
            RingTime,DelayTime,TimeToAband,
            HoldTime,WorkTime,b.LocalQTime,
            CallSegmentTime,ConferenceTime as ConferenceTime,
            NetworkSkillGroupQTime,EnterpriseQueueTime FROM TCDRecords a, callType1prepare b
  WHERE a.RouterCallKeyDay = b.RouterCallKeyDay
  and a.RouterCallKey = b.RouterCallKey
  and a.Duration = b.Duration 
),
CallType1(RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,DateTime, DigitsDialed, DNIS, 

ANI,CallDisposition,NetworkTime,Duration,RingTime,DelayTime,TimeToAband,HoldTime,
  WorkTime,LocalQTime,CallSegmentTime,ConferenceTime,NetworkSkillGroupQTime,EnterpriseQueueTime)
AS
(

            SELECT RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,DateTime, DigitsDialed, DNIS, ANI,CallDisposition,NetworkTime,
            Duration,
            RingTime,DelayTime,TimeToAband,
            HoldTime,WorkTime,LocalQTime,
            CallSegmentTime,ConferenceTime as ConferenceTime,
            NetworkSkillGroupQTime,EnterpriseQueueTime FROM CallType1PrepareDistinct WHERE RowNumber = 1
),
CallType2
(RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,CallDisposition,AgentSkillTargetID,SkillGroupSkillTargetID,
AgentPeripheralNumber,HoldTime,TalkTime,WorkTime,
DateTime, DigitsDialed, DNIS, ANI)
As
(
           SELECT 

RouterCallKeyDay,RouterCallKey,CallDisposition,AgentSkillTargetID,SkillGroupSkillTargetID,AgentPeripheralNumber,HoldTime

,TalkTime,WorkTime,
           DateTime, DigitsDialed, DNIS, ANI
 from TCDRecords  WHERE PeripheralCallType =2
)
select 
p1.RouterCallKey as RouterCallkey,
p1.RouterCallKeyDay as RouterCallKeyDay, 
p1.DateTime ,
AgentPeripheralNumber,
AgentSkillTargetID,
SkillGroupSkillTargetID,
p1.DigitsDialed as DNIS,
p1.ANI,
p2.TalkTime,
p2.HoldTime,
p2.WorkTime,
Duration,
p2.DNIS as Extension,
p1.LocalQTime as LocalQTime,
CD.Hangup_Flag
from CallType1 p1 
left outer join CallType2 p2 
on p1.RouterCallKey = p2.RouterCallKey 
and p1.RouterCallKeyDay = p2.RouterCallKeyDay
left outer join CallDisposition CD
on p1.RouterCallKey = CD.RouterCallKey 
and p1.RouterCallKeyDay = CD.RouterCallKeyDay;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to bind column names to variables, but you can achieve similar results by using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @datetxt varchar(10) = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @sqltxt nvarchar(1000); 

SET @sqltxt = N'SELECT dateAdd(second, 1, ' + @datetxt + ') AS StartTime FROM Termination_Call_Detail'
Exec (@sqltxt)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly what you're looking to do should be quite simple.

I'm not entirely sure how you're setting `@date1` but for this to work you will need to set that as a SSIS variable and for this example I'll assum it's a date. Then you need to create your query as a variable and then set it as an expression like so.

[image: Expression]

Then you set your expression and replace your question mark with your variable and which you type cast to a string like so.

`"select dateAdd(second, 1,@date1= "+ (DT_STR, 50, 1252) @[User::Date1]  + " ) StartTime,
convert(datetime, convert(char(19), dateAdd(minute, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 120)) EndTime"`

[image]

Then in your OLEDB task simply select query from variable and you're good to go.

[image: SQLFromVariable]

[image: FreeHand]

Comment: missing complementary `@dis1` variable